# using outline on font awsome icon focus

Tags: css, focus, accessibility, font-awesome

I am trying to put outline on a font awsome while navigating with keyboard, but it is not working. I tried to add aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1" like suggested in another post but it still doesn´t work.

```
<div class="faContainer"> 
<a class="homeAnchor" href="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1"> 
<i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"> 
</i> 
</a> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
a:focus{
  outline: 3px solid white;
}
```

tried also targeting i element

Comment: are you aware that the color you set is white? you code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qw9xdn1g/

Comment: yes, my background color is dark. Hmm yeah it works fine in your fiddle so it has to be another problem in CSS but I can not identify it

Answer (score 0):

Few issues to address here:-

### Never use positive tab index

A positive tab index disrupts the natural tabbing order, you want `tabindex="0"` in order to make something that isn't normally focusable able to accept focus. It is also not needed in your example as `<a>` elements are focusable by default.

### aria-hidden has nothing to do with focus

`aria-hidden` is to do with the accessibility tree. By adding this attribute you are telling assistive technology (i.e. screen readers) to ignore this item. Remove this.

### empty hrefs can get ignored

Your `href=""` attribute can be ignored in certain circumstances as it is not a valid hyperlink.

Add `href="#"` during testing if you do not know the URL you want to point it at currently.

If it is going to be used to make a change on the current page use a `<button>` element instead as that is semantically correct (i.e. it is going to work with a JavaScript function rather than function as a link).

### how to find out why outline isn't working

The above CSS (on a dark theme) should work fine.

On Google Chrome -> Open developer tools (F12) -> inspect the element.

Top right you will see `Filter :hov .cls +`

Select `:hov` and click the `:focus` checkbox.

There will be a rule set that is over-riding your `a:focus` rule, either by being more specific (e.g. `a.homeanchor:focus`) or by using `!important`.

That rule is likely to be `outline:0` or `outline:none` so you could also try doing a search within your CSS for those terms to identify the issue.